# JavaScript self invoking function

Tags: javascript, function, timeout

I'm trying to understand this example code, what is the function of line 15, why `start(timeout)`? (Sorry, I'm new to programming)

```
var schedule = function (timeout, callbackfunction) {
    return {
        start: function () {
            setTimeout(callbackfunction, timeout)
        }
    };
};

(function () {
    var timeout = 1000; // 1 second
    var count = 0;
    schedule(timeout, function doStuff() {
        console.log(++count);
        schedule(timeout, doStuff);
    }).start(timeout);
})();

// "timeout" and "count" variables
 // do not exist in this scope.
```

Comment: That code involves something possibly confusing - the parameter passed in the call to `.start()` is ignored by that function.

Comment: Are you recieving a scope error? If you are, it's because you declared timeout and count in the function, and they aren't available outside said function..

Comment: Actually it's wrong in other ways. Where does it come from?

Comment: this example code is from the book HANDS ON NODEJS by Pedro Teixeira

Comment: @user1477955: Are you absolutely sure the example is **exactly** as shown above? If so, then that doesn't reflect well on the book at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function schedule is executed as a function. That function returns an object. Like you can see with the `{ start... }`. With the returned object it calls out the `start` function. This is called chaining. So the `start` function is executed after is set the function.

What is strange is that the timeout is passed to the `start` function which has no parameters.

Comment: Also strange is that inside the callback, the "schedule()" function is called, but that's pointless as its return value is just another one of those objects; there's no call to ".start()" in other words.

Answer (score 3):

> ...why start(timeout)?

In that example, there's actually no reason for passing `timeout` into `start`, since `start` doesn't accept or use any arguments. The call may as well be `.start()`.

What's happening is that `schedule` *returns* an object the `schedule` function creates, and one of the properties on that object is called `start`, which is a function. When `start` is called, it sets up a timed callback via `setTimeout` using the *original* timeout passed into `schedule` and the callback function passed into `schedule`.

The code calling `schedule` turns around and immediately calls the `start` function on the object it creates.

In the comments, Pointy points out (well, he would, wouldn't he?) that the callback function is calling `schedule` but not doing anything with the returned object, which is pointless — `schedule` doesn't do anything other than create and return the object, so not using the returned object makes the call pointless.

Here's the code with those two issues addressed:

```
var schedule = function (timeout, callbackfunction) {
    return {
        start: function () {
            setTimeout(callbackfunction, timeout)
        }
    };
};

(function () {
    var timeout = 1000; // 1 second
    var count = 0;
    schedule(timeout, function doStuff() {
        console.log(++count);
        schedule(timeout, doStuff).start(); // <== Change here
    }).start();                             // <== And here
})();
```

It's not very good code, though, frankly, even with the fixes. There's no particularly good reason for creating a new object every time, and frankly if the book is meant to be teaching, this example could be a lot clearer. Inline named function expressions and calls to methods on objects returned by a function...absolutely fine, but not for *teaching*. Still, I don't know the context, so those comments come with a grain of salt.

Here's a reworked version of using the `schedule` function by *reusing* the object it returns, and being clear about what bit is happening when:

```
(function () {
    var timeout = 1000; // 1 second
    var count = 0;

    // Create the schedule object
    var scheduleObject = schedule(timeout, doStuff);

    // Set up the first timed callback
    scheduleObject.start();

    // This is called by each timed callback
    function doStuff() {
        // Show the count
        console.log(++count);

        // Set up the next timed callback
        scheduleObject.start();
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your Code is much better to understand, thank you for the good explanations.