# checked radiobutton on checkbox change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how we checked or unchecked all radiobutton on checkbox click.. if checkbox checked then all radiobutton also checked and vice versa.. it is not working properly

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Check" />SelectAll<br /><input type="radio"/>First<br />


    <input type="radio"/>Second<br />
            <input type="radio"/>Third<br />
            <input type="radio"/>Fourth<br />
            <input type="radio"/>Fifth</div>
            <script>
                var IsCheck = false;
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#Check").change(function () {
                        if (IsCheck == false) {
                            $("input[type=radio]").attr("checked", true);
                            IsCheck == true
                        }
                        else { $("input[type=radio]").attr("checked", false); IsCheck == false }
                    });
                }); </script>
```

Comment: I dont think radio is the right choice http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_button usually only one option in a group is selected

Comment: Please don't use radiobuttons for that

Comment: (Important) side note: `var IsCheck = false;` introduces a global variable, which [is a bad thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10525582/why-are-global-variables-considered-bad-practice-javascript). Wrap your JavaScript code inside a [self-invoking function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313163/javascript-self-invoking-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {                    
    $("#Check").change(function () {                        
      $("input[type=radio]").attr("checked", $("#Check").is(":checked"));                            
    });
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xabpL/)

Answer (score 3):

Take care you were just comparing operands instead of assigning to a variable in this statements:

```
IsCheck == true  
         ^------ REMOVE ONE = so it's an assignment
```

Also, don't use `.attr("checked", true);` the correct form is:

```
$("input[type=radio]").attr("checked", 'checked'); //checking for jQuery < 1.6
```

And unchecking:

```
$("input[type=radio]").removeAttr("checked");  //unchecking for jQuery < 1.6
```

---

If you are using jQuery > 1.6 you can use the `.prop()` method with a boolean, which is similar to how you were trying to use it:

```
$("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true); //checking for jQuery >= 1.6
$("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false); //unchecking for jQuery >= 1.6
```

Answer (score 2):

For jQuery 1.9 or higher use

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop("checked", true)
```

Otherwise try

```
 $('input[type=radio]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 1):

For your question, this could be the answer :

```
$("#Check").change(function () {
    $("input:radio").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/QSx29/

That said, radio buttons are not the best way of doing this. Its not *semantically* right. You can have only one radio button selected in a group. Try using checkboxes instead. Try to change you're markup to this :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Check" />SelectAll
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />First
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />Second
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />Third
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />Fourth
<br />
<input type="checkbox" />Fifth</div>
```

And replace the JS code to this :

```
$("#Check").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Here's a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/QSx29/1/

Answer (score 1):

You just need this

```
$("#Check").change(function () {
    $("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

Demo `---->` http://jsfiddle.net/kLnyD/

Comment: $("input[type=radio]") +1 for most effective code and first to use prop

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/4u9sQ/

```
 $("#Check").change(function () {
                        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                            $("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);

                        }
                        else { $("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", false); }
                    });
```